# looking for a good explanation on how html gets rendered and how css effects it

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a tutorial that explains how css/html gets rendered. I must be using the incorrect search terms. All i can find is tutorials like : This is a div....

I use CSS alot but would like a better understanding of how the page gets rendered.
Understanding the flow so why i put things in certain order and how they are styled the behave differently.

for example: if i style

```
       .etype{
            width: 17px;
            height: 11px;
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            margin-top:5px;
        }
```

i have to put the etype divs first for them to display after href

```
<li class="avail-items">
    <div class="etype edit-page"></div>
    <div class="etype view-page"></div>
    <span class="ptype"></span> 
    <a class="pages-manage" href="#"><?=$item->label?></a>
 </li>
```

Thanks

Comment: html and css are script languages. Means the browser has somewhere in its source some kind of dictionary that translates the tags, attributes and values in functions written in the native language. I assume that is for most browsers C++, but don't nail me on that.

Comment: it's called "normal flow of the document". Pick up books/tuts on CSS Positioning & DOM

Comment: @Sven Bieder: JavaScript is a scripting language. HTML and CSS are not.

Comment: @BoltClock: When you want to go in the nerdy details, then you are right, html is a markup language and css is a style sheet language, because they have no decision-making abilities. But for the process how they are rendered in the browser that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like this explanation as it's very thorough:

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Comment: That is indeed very helpful. +1